# What are all the places(folders) that the Ubuntu system uses to store Application data?

Tags: user-data

I have installed and uninstalled several applications over several months. So if i could know the specific folders that are used to store app data, registry data etc, i could clear the unwanted ones.
This info is would also be helpful if i wanted to reinstall a specifif application.

Comment: Some information are stored in .appName in your home folder like, .Chrome these are some of the hidden files from applications, if you wish to remove all hidden files when removing a program use `purge` instead of remove.

Comment: @Alvar I'm not sure if they are also talking about user data too? Unfortunately there are a few places these could be. e.g. `~/.app_name`, `~/.config/app_name`, `~/.local/share/app_name`.

Comment: Also `~/.cache/app_name`. Sometimes there's an additional directory level for the application vendor. Linux doesn't have a “registry“ like Windows. If you let the package manager manage your software, *purging* a package also removes system-wide configuration data, which is of negligible size.

Answer (score 0):

#### Install ubuntu Tweak

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After installing open Ubuntu tweak from dash:

[image]

Select "Janitor" tabs and select "Apps" and select what you want to delete/remove and press **"Clean"** button(bottom right corner).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you uninstall an application, ubuntu (debian's system) keep an copy of the packages to the /var/cache/apt/archives directory. To If you want to make a clean uninstall, you have to follow theses steps:

- if you want to uninstall whithout delete dependencies, do this:

`sudo apt-get purge <package(s)>`

- in you want to uninstall a packages whith dependencies, do this:

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge <package(s)>`

note that you can do `sudo apt-get clean` or `sudo apt-get autoclean` to clean your cache by deleting all uninstalled packages